# Deploying a new VM with Vagrant and AWS user-data not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, puppet

I have a provisioning setup with vagrant and puppet that works well locally and I'm now tryign to move it to AWS using [vagrant-aws](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws).

As I understand it I can make use the AWS user-data field in vagrant as specified to run commands on the first boot of a new vm like so:

```
aws.user_data = File.read("user_data.txt")
```

Where user_data.txt contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install -y puppet-common
```

Then my existing puppet provisioning scripts should be able to run. However this errors out on the vagrant up command with:

```
[aws] Running provisioner: puppet...
The `puppet` binary appears to not be in the PATH of the guest. This
could be because the PATH is not properly setup or perhaps Puppet is not
installed on this guest. Puppet provisioning can not continue without
Puppet properly installed.
```

But when I ssh into the machine I see that the user-data did get parsed and puppet is installed successfully. Is the puppet provisioner running before the user-data install puppet maybe? Or is there some better way to install puppet on a vm before trying to provision?

Comment: Did you try

    #cloud-config
    packages:
      - puppet-common

in your user-data.txt file?

Answer (score 2):

It is broken, but there's a workaround if you're using Ubuntu which is far simpler than building your own AMI.

Add the following line to your config:

```
aws.user_data = "#cloud-config\nbootcmd:\n - echo 'manual' > /etc/init/ssh.override\npackages:\n - puppet\nruncmd:\n - [ 'rm', '/etc/init/ssh.override' ]\n - [ 'service', 'ssh', 'start' ]\n"
```

This tells Cloudinit to disable SSH startup early in the boot process and re-enable it once your packages are installed. Now Vagrant can only SSH in to run puppet once the packages are fully installed.

This will probably work for other distros that use Cloudinit aside from Ubuntu, altho it is Upstart specific so the commands may need tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Well I worked around this by building my own AMI with puppet and other things I need installed, still seems like vagrant-aws is broken or I'm misunderstanding something else here.